# html meta tag wont work in other pages

Tags: html, css, character-encoding, meta, utf

I have HomePage(index.html) and other pages. Other pages can open by clicking on home page. and i added all pages `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="UTF-8" />` to see turkish characters. but that meta working only on home page when i click other pages then couldnt read turkish characters.

Here is the homepage's head section

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="UTF-8" />
 <title>Welcome to my page</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css">
    
</head>

<body>

 <ul>
  <li><a href="index.html">Home Page</a></li>
  <li><a href="pages/sozDizimi.html">Söz Dizimi</a></li>
  <li><a href="pages/behavior.html">Behavior</a></li>
  <li><a href="pages/habitat.html">Habitat</a></li>
 </ul>
......
```

Here is the some of my other page

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Söz Dizimi</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/mystyle.css">
 </head>
 
 <body>
 
  <ul>
   <li><a href="../index.html">Home Page</a></li>
   <li><a href="sozDizimi.html">Söz Dizimi</a></li>
   <li><a href="behavior.html">Behavior</a></li>
   <li><a href="habitat.html">Habitat</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: second page charset is `charset="iso-8859-9"`

Comment: your meta tag in the other pages is different...

Comment: sorry i was added charset="iso-8859-9" maybe fix my problem but didnt work too... and i forget change it  when i copy it @bansi

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Notice that their is no " before utf.

Comment: i copy paste your code. now other one work but homepage doesnt. also i forget to say those pages arent at the same folder. right now i upload a video u can see more clear @turtile

Comment: i move the index.html to folder which is other pages in this folder. then start working but when i open with notepad ++ i see like xFC xE7 xFO this things instead of turkish characters. nvm i guess some kind of bug but now working

Comment: Did you set the encoding in Notepad++ to UTF-8 too?

Comment: it is set to utf-8 without bom. should i change it to only utf-8 ?